# Как вывести все сессии, которые существуют PHP

Tags: php, сессия

Работаю с сессиями в PHP, которые хранятся на серверной стороне. Задания состоит в том, чтобы не подключатся к БД. После того, как несколько человек вошли, мне нужно вывести все сессии. Не очень понимаю как ето сделать... При написании print_r($_SESSION); выводит только текущую сессию. Как мне вывести их все вместе?

Comment: Сессии не предназначены для того, чтобы выводить их чужим людям

Comment: @andreymal У меня задание, просто вывести вcе сессии, которые существуют

Comment: `print_r(scandir(session_save_path()));`

Comment: Скорее всего задача сформулирована по-другому, просто ты придумал что решить ее можно именно так.

Comment: @u_mulder у меня допустим вошло на сайт 2 пользователя, которые при входе вводили логин и пароль, то мне в специальном окне нужно вывести их логины и пароли

Comment: Ну так в момент нажатия на кнопку "Войти" сохрани данные в файл.

Comment: а лучше в базу.